# had never thought with would

Tags: past-tense

"I had never thought I would be surprised again  in my life until I did it ."

Does it work ? I think so because doing this thing makes the man realised he had not thought about it before.But it seems that "had never thought with would" is very rarely used . I have never found it so it may be wrong .

Comment: until I was: to be surprised. Please fix your punctuation.

Comment: why until" I was"  and "not until I did it" because  the man did a thing that he thought he could not do and that surprised him the fact that  he could  do it

Comment: If *did* refers to some action he accomplished, you need to state it. What is it that he did? Otherwise, it seems like you are only talking about being surprised. For example: I had never thought I would be surprised again in my life until I [bungee jumped].

Comment: Doing (whatever it was) surprised him. He hadn't expected to be surprised until he did it. (But a surprise is, by definition, something you don't expect!)

Comment: P l e a s e d o n't p u t s p a c e s b e f o r e E n g l i s h p u n c t u a t i o n.:)

Answer (score 2):

The use of *Past Perfect* in the cited context is syntactically valid. But it's utterly pointless, since Simple Past ***I** never **thought** I would be surprised again...* means ***exactly*** the same.

Native speakers usually avoid using Perfect verb forms unnecessarily